# Subrayado azul enlaces no se quita

Tags: html, css

Tengo unos enlaces en html, pero a pesaar de tener el

```
textdecoration : none sigue igual
```

¿Cómo lo quito?

```css
.menu-elem {
  color: #75848B!important;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

body,
div,
img,
span,
p,
a {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

form {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

html {
  background-color: #DEDEDF;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 80px; background-color: white">
  <div class="centrado" style="width: 1200px; height: 100%;">
    <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/logo.png" style="max-height: 48px; margin-top: 16px;" />
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #122633">
  <div class="centrado" style="width: 1200px; height: 100%;">
    <div class="menu-elem">
      <a href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/admin/clientes/consulta.xhtml">Administración</a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-elem">
      <a href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/operacion/lineas/lineas.xhtml">Operación</a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-elem">
      <a>Reportes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resulto que el problema solamente era cosa de borrar el caché y las cookies.

Answer (score 2):

intenta con esto:

```
a:visited, a:hover, a:link, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema parecer solo ser:

```
default :
```

porque sino funciona correctamente

```css
a{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2ee;
}
```

```html
<a href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/operacion/lineas/lineas.xhtml">Operación</a>
    </div>
```